# Can I see what comments were upvoted?

Tags: support, comments, comment-votes

Today I earned the [Pundit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/94/pundit) badge, which got me thinking about which comments were upvoted often. If they were standard-ish replies, I could save them somewhere since apparently they work well.

I only found [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148008/how-can-i-see-comments-that-ive-upvoted) from 2012 saying that it should be possible, but I can't see a category `Votes` on said page.

Can it be done? If yes, where? If not, is it possible to implement? I can imagine only a very small percentage of users interested in this, so it might not be worth implementing. Still, I'm wondering :-)

Comment: By the way I created a copy of Erik A's query, except for Meta Stack Overflow! https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/revision/1347846/1658344/top-10-comments-for-meta-stack-overflow

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can easily view your top scoring comments by using [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/872369/my-top-scoring-comments):

```sql
SELECT Top 10 Id as [Comment Link], PostId As [Post Link], Score, Text, CreationDate
FROM Comments
WHERE UserId = ##UserId##
ORDER BY Score DESC
```

Just enter your user ID.

I don't think search functionality for comments, besides SEDE, will get implemented.

Comment: Oh hey, this is cool enough for me. Didn't even know that site existed.

Comment: Instead of `Text` in the `SELECT`, you can use `Id as [Comment Link]`

Comment: Apparently, "This question is being discussed on Meta." can get some upvotes. Same for "possible duplicate" comments. *sigh* Maybe I should leave some funny comments every now and then?

Comment: To add to what @Arulkumar said, when you have the comment link, there's no need to also select the Text, since the comment link includes the entire text.

Comment: I've added the column as per Arulkumar's suggestion. @Magisch There's no real harm either I think. It's easier to read for me (and I don't know how much it increases load, probably not much)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth from a load standpoint, using magic links is really bad, so just the text or even a compound expression assembling the magic link yourself would be a lot more performant.

Comment: @Justastudent: Possible duplicate comments automatically get upvotes when close votes are cast to agree. They can also get upvotes the usual way of course.

Comment: I am painfully aware of that fact, @Nathan (-:

Comment: Planning on leaving funny comments? Best check if you can run your query for flagged comments as well first! [_Flagged as Unwelcoming_]